# I need to add Javascript to Wordpress theme called Juridica

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I did slider for photos on my site but I don't know where to put this into  Juridica theme. This is slider code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var numer = Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1;

            var timer1 = 0;
            var timer2 = 0;

            function ustawslajd(nrslajdu)
            {
                clearTimeout(timer1);
                clearTimeout(timer2);
                numer = nrslajdu - 1;

                schowaj();
                setTimeout("zmienslajd()", 500);

            }

            function schowaj()
            {
                $("#slider").fadeOut(500);
            }

            function zmienslajd()
            {
                numer++; if (numer>5) numer=1;

                var plik = "<img src=\"slajdy/slajd" + numer + ".png\" />";

                document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML = plik;
                $("#slider").fadeIn(500);

                timer1 = setTimeout("zmienslajd()", 5000);
                timer2 = setTimeout("schowaj()", 4500);

            }

</script>
```

And question where is this theme's html?

Comment: Start looking here if you want to do it properly and can manage some PHP code - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Theme directory under the wp-content/themes/your theme name/

Also please refer the [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function to add a script in the WordPress theme.